# Add Activity indicator to web view and change the colour of it

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview

How do I add activity indicator to web view?

And also change color ?

I have the following code currently

```
[super viewDidLoad];
NSString *fullURL = @"http://conecode.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_viewWeb loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Comment: change color of what?

Comment: you can make a control the child of any view, including the web view.  activity indicator allows setColor to any UIColor